How to competently open and manage a browser using WinAPI
I'm making a YouTube player and I need the following:

Open a new browser process and open a link in it.

Wait for it all to load

Minimize the window


I also need:
When pressing PAUSE, pause the video, when pressing Play, resume playback
Problem:
I can actually start the process with the command CreateProcess, but I can't determine the state: whether the window has loaded or not. Because if I minimize the window, but the video or browser does not close, it either will not work, or the video will not start playing.
Sleep does not work for me, because on different computers and depending on the user's Internet speed, the window and video can load in different amounts of time, so it is impossible to guess here.
I also encountered a problem with finding the window. When I open a process and try to find the browser window (EnumWindows), it most often does not find it. I also tried to use the enumeration of all windows and match ProcessId - did not work either.
Below I have provided some code from my attempts (primitively done specifically for testing):
Creating a process:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

struct handle_data {
    unsigned long process_id;
    HWND window_handle;
};

BOOL CALLBACK enum_windows_callback(const HWND handle, const LPARAM lParam)
{
    handle_data& data = *reinterpret_cast<handle_data *>(lParam);
    unsigned long process_id = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &process_id);
    if (data.process_id != process_id)
        return TRUE;
    data.window_handle = handle;
    return FALSE;
}

HWND find_main_window(unsigned long process_id)
{
    handle_data data{};
    data.process_id = process_id;
    data.window_handle = nullptr;
    EnumWindows(enum_windows_callback, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&data));
    return data.window_handle;
}

int main() {
    const char* chromePath = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
    std::string command = std::string(chromePath) + " --new-window " + url;

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess(
        NULL,
        const_cast<LPSTR>(command.c_str()),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        std::cerr << "CreateProcess failed with error code " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hwnd = find_main_window(pi.dwProcessId);

    if (hwnd != NULL) {
        std::cout << "Found window handle: " << hwnd << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Window not found." << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}

This is what I tried to find the window of the running process (for some reason it doesn't work). I also think that this is a primitive approach and does not take into account a large number of points, but I do not know of any other way.
In fact, I need all this to manage this window in the future (pause, play, etc.).
Can you suggest other methods besides winapi, maybe there are more effective methods to do what I described above?
I also need to take into account that the user may have multiple browser processes running.

Browsers these days are enormously complex; even if you get this working, it will break next month and you won't know why. Is there a reason you're not using an embedded web browser designed for automation, like WebView2 or Chromium Embedded Framework?

@tenfour There are no reasons as such, but I don’t want to embed the content, I just want to play the audio part of it, and the easiest way seemed to me to simply open and minimize the browser window.
Is it possible to use an embedded web browser in such a simple solution? And does this make sense?

Most browsers provide an automation api, look up selenium, note that those APIs work on IPC.

Embedding a web browser is simpler than trying to launch one and control it, because an embedded browser API conforms to an expected behavior. Making assumptions about how Chrome works will be a never-ending chase based on assumptions. For example your app assumes that Chrome is a single process. In fact a single Chrome tab will launch many processes to do various things like GPU rendering, sandboxing, etc. I would not suggest chasing after those behaviors unless there's a very specific need that requires it.

@tenfour Okay. thatks, i will try.

@AhmedAEK I saw this library (selenium) but it doesn't come for C++! I only came across some unpopular similarity on github (webdriverxx)

The easiest way is to use webview2.

The best approach is to use the embedded webview2 browser.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
